# Play next html5 audio when one above it finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, media-player

Hello I have a series of audio clips.

```
<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="aduio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="aduio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="aduio3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="aduio4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>
```

In my actual code the audio is spread out through a large wordpress page.

I was wondering if it was possible to play the next one after one above it finishes? For example if one near the top of html is played then it will find the next down and play that, and so one.

For example if someone pressed play on the first one and it finished till the end. The one below it would start playing, and so on.

Another example if someone hit play on the 3rd one and that one finished, Then the 4th one would start playing.

Thanks for any help!

(think podcast site)

Comment: Did you try any code? Any script on your own?

Comment: can you share me your url?

Comment: in general, you're looking for an `Event` to `add` a `Listener` to

Comment: I am working on it locally. However this is the theme and their live preview is the same setup

Comment: https://themeforest.net/item/dixie-podcast-and-audio-wordpress-theme/20635268

Comment: My friend is here trying to code the JS and he is trying to fetch all the mp3s on the page and build an array first. Which i think is over kill

Comment: my advice is to start getting the next one when the currently playing one is some percentage (50?) through playing, that'll make the transitions smoother without pre-downloading everything :p - again, this can be triggered by `add`ing an appropriate `Event` handler or `Listener`

Comment: That does sound better, but still seems overkill right? Why cant he just trigger the next play button on the page after the current one finishes?

Comment: sure, sounds perfectly cromulent to do it that way as well - there will (may) be a "gap" in audio though - depends if you want a smooth transition or not

Comment: he said his problem is finding the next mp3 player on the page below i guess.. Any thoughts?

Comment: I linked the theme above, their preview is our exact setup

Comment: If you really want to simulate simply clicking those buttons use `document.querySelectorAll('button[title="Play"]');` to get all play buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach `ended` event to `".audio-wrapper audio"` selector, check if `$(this).parent(".audio-wrapper").next(".audio-wrapper")` exists using `.is()`, if true, call `.play()`

```js
const src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/%22Pollinate%22-_Logic_Synth_and_Effects_Demonstration.ogg";

$(".audio-wrapper audio")
.each(function() {
  this.src = src;
})
.on("ended", function(event) {
  let next = $(this).parent(".audio-wrapper")
             .next(".audio-wrapper").find("audio");
  console.log(next)
  if (next.is("*")) {
    next[0].play()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio controls>
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio controls>
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio controls>
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio controls>
    </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: We are using this logic along side the last comment "walk" made. Will let u know outcome soon. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @PortalP See updated post. `.play()` needs to be called on DOM element, not jQuery object